# Ionic 3 - FAB - Floating Action Button - <ion-fab> Complete list of possible position attributes

Tags: ionic3, floating-action-button

I've seen various examples/looked in various places...:

- [component documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#fabs) (top right edge / right bottom)
- [FAB Container](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/fab/FabContainer/) (top right / center middle)
- [Fab Button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/fab/FabButton/) (mini)
- [FAB List](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/fab/FabList/) (side="top" /side="left")
- I am also aware of [CSS Utilities](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/) (doesn't scratch my itch here)
- [Github source for FAB](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/src/components/fab)

But I've yet to see a definitive list of all the possible attributes for placement locations/size etc you can assign as attributes to a `<ion-fab>`.

**Can someone either list them, or point me to where I can see them.**

Many thanks in advance. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/fab/fab-container.ts

- @property [top] - Places the container on the top of the content
- @property [bottom] - Places the container on the bottom  of the content
- @property [left] - Places the container on the left
- @property [right] - Places the container on the right
- @property [middle] - Places the container on the middle vertically
- @property [center] - Places the container on the center horizontally
- @property [edge] - Used to place the container between the content and the header/footer